# No HDMI audio after blank screen

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with an Nvidia GPU and Nvidia driver. My monitor is connected via HDMI and has built-in speakers. The audio through my monitor speakers usually works fine, but when I return from a screen lock/blank I cannot output audio to the monitor anymore.

If I open settings > sound, the HDMI monitor no longer even appears as an audio output device (only "Digital Output S/PDIF" appears). If I then run `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`, then close and reopen settings > sound, I can find my HDMI monitor among the audio output devices again and select it.

**Is there a way to make Ubuntu automatically recognize and continue outputting audio to my HDMI monitor speakers after returning from a screen lock/blank?**